# How to exclude packages from a context using @WebMvcTest

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot

I want to [test application slices](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4#testing-application-slices), but there is a package I want to exclude, since it is not related to those tests at all.

I am trying to exclude the package this way:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = MyController.class,
        excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(
                type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com.foo.bar.*")})
public class MyControllerTest {
    // ... list of test methods goes here ...
}
```

Classes from this package are included in a context anyway. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing * sign in the pattern attribute, like this :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = MyController.class,
        excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com.foo.bar.*")})
public class MyControllerTest {
    // ... list of test methods goes here ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with * or not. Have you tried it? I'll edit my question